# React Native, Chrome, logging full error object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, react-native, error-handling

I have a Native module with React Native on IOS that rejects an error.

I am trying to log the error with a `console.log` but Chrome format the error and I can't see clearly what is the actual anatomy of the error.

In Objective-C, I have:

`reject(@"ios_under_10_3", @"IOS Version is under 10.3", nil);` of type `RCTPromiseRejectBlock`

and on the javascript side a simple console.log:

```
NativeModules.MyApp.triggerRateAppModal().catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
```

In Chrome I see a formatted log like this :

```
Error: IOS Version is under 10.3
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:155)
    at NativeModules.js:104
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:414)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:80
```

but it doesn't tell me anywhere that my error has, for example, an `error.code` property or `error.message` property.

Is there a way to log the full error object?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I was wondering the same thing. If I do JSON.stringify(error) then I see the dataincluding the error code and message but not in the console.log()